# Get href string with more than one class using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this link...

```
<a class="class sub1 class2" href="test.asp?Code=2D3824&ID=1">
```

I need to get the ID value in the href. I tried:

```
jQuery("a.class.sub1.class2[href$='2D3824']").text();
```

To try and get a string to break up, but it comes back empty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string always has the same format :

```
jQuery("a.class.sub1.class2[href*='2D3824']").attr('href').split('=')[2];
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jyh6G/)

To get the value based on the querystring key with a regex:

```
jQuery("a.class.sub1.class2[href*='2D3824']").attr('href').match(/\&ID\=(.*?)$/)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the property for the href, not the text of the anchor, and you also need to use the contains selector, *=.

jQuery("a.class.sub1.class2[href*='2D3824']").prop('href').split('=')[2];